# How do you explicitly initialize a reference in c++?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class SomeClass {};

class SomeOtherClass {
    SomeClass& someObj;
public:
    SomeOtherClass() {someObj = SomeClass();}
};
```

And I get an error on the constructor for `SomeOtherClass` saying `Constructor for 'SomeOtherClass' must explicitly initialize the reference member 'someObj'`.

So I guess my question is pretty strait forward. How do you initialize a reference?

Comment: Under the hood, a reference isn't all that different from a pointer...it just has to be initialized (no "nulls") and can't be changed once you've initialized it.  If your intention is to safely hold on to an object you are allocating--and a typical member variable by value won't suffice--look into the use of [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), such as `shared_ptr<SomeClass> someObj;` or `unique_ptr<SomeClass> someObj;`...and an initialization with `someObj (new SomeClass())`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to store a reference to a temporary object that is being destructed immediately, so that will definately go wrong; even when using the constructor initialization lists described in the other answers.

A reference should point to an object that is being stored elsewhere, just like a pointer. Are you sure you even need to use a reference in this case?

Comment: Well actually now that I think of it, I may not need references to do what I'm currently trying to do. But I'd still like to know how to do this. So are you saying the other two answers are wrong then? Should I be using `someObj(*new SomeClass())` instead?

Comment: I guess so. Cause the other two answers were giving me errors, but using `*new` made it work.

Comment: Using `*new` will result in a memory leak, because now you're unable to free the allocated memory for this object (unless you coerce the reference back to a pointer). I'd recommend either making `someObj` a pointer, or no pointer or reference at all (meaning you store the `SomeClass` directly in the `SomeOtherClass`).

Comment: Wow, I learned a lot more from your answers than I was expecting to. Thanks. So what your saying is that having a `SomeClass&` as a member of another class is always a bad idea and to use a `SomeClass *` instead?

Comment: @MichaelDorst it isn't necessarily a bad idea to hold a reference as a data member, and it is not the same as holding a pointer. So it really depends on what you want. If you want to be able to reassign your data member, or have a valid null value, then a reference won't do. I have fixed my answer BTW.

Comment: @Michael Dorst: I personally think so, because I don't really see the point of the option to store references as class members. Doing so also makes some matters more complicated, while storing a pointer is more clear and slightly less error-prone.

Comment: Well for what I'm trying to do, `someObj` won't be used at all until the new one is passed in by the call operator (I'm creating a functor for use with `std::thread`), so would it work to initialize `someObj` to `nullptr`?

Comment: It depends, if you want the `someObj` to be created along with the `SomeOtherClass` that is holding it and be destroyed along with it as well: make a regular member. If you want to add the `someObj` later and potentionally remove it again, you might indeed want to make it a pointer that is initialized as null and will point to something later. In that case, you shouldn't forget deleting the underlying `SomeClass`-object before nothing points to it anymore.

Answer (score 7):

As part of the [constructor initialization list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6):

```
SomeOtherClass() : someObj(SomeClass()) {}
```

**Update:** I should really have cautioned that this is something you should not use verbatim, because it's going to result in a reference to the soon-to-be-dead temporary object instance.

The idea is the above, but you will have to pass in an object with lifetime no shorter than that of the `SomeOtherClass` instance you are constructing.

Comment: and what happens after the temporary `SomeClass()` is destructed? You've got a dangling reference.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Murderous omission. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You can't initialize references to non-const with rvalues. `someObj(SomeClass())` won't even compile.

Answer (score 4):

You have to initialize it in the constructor's initialization list, since there is no "default" or "null" initialization for a reference:

```
class SomeOtherClass {
    SomeClass& someObj;
public:
    SomeOtherClass(SomeClass& sc) : someObj(sc) {}
};
```

**Edit** as has been pointed out in another answer, you should take care that your reference is initialized to an object whose lifetime is the same or longer than the object containing the reference. In the example above, assume `sc` outlives the `SomeOtherClass` instance.